# AsyncTask blocking UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

I know there are a few similar questions here, but none of them seem to answer my problem.

My `MainActivity` calls my `AsyncTask` as follows:

```
new ParkLoader(MainActivity.this, new OnLoadCompleted() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadCompleted(ArrayList<Park> parks) {
                    showList(parks);
                }
            }).execute();
```

`OnLoadCompleted` is an interface that is called in `AsyncTask`. The AsyncTask looks like this:

```
public class ParkLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    public ParkLoader(Activity activity, OnLoadCompleted listener) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if (isServicesEnabled())
            findNearbyParks();
        else
           findParks();
        return null;
    } 

[...]
```

The FindParks() methods are responsible for calling OnLoadCompleted. Now my problem is that every time the MainActivity calls the AsyncTask it freezes the UI thread. The AsyncTask makes use of an `Activity` reference (because I saw that reference to the Activity's `Context` is known to cause UI freezes), however is doesnt make any updates to the UI.

Any help is really appreciated.

EDIT: The code in AsyncTask:

```
private void findNearbyParks() {
    locationProvider = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
    try {
        if (locationPermissionsGranted) {
            final Task location = locationProvider.getLastLocation();

            location.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                    Location currentLocation = (Location) location.getResult();
                    ArrayList<Park> parks = getParks();

                    if (currentLocation != null)
                        for (int i = 0; i < parks.size(); i++)
                            parks.get(i).setDistance(Distance.getDistance(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), parks.get(i)));
                    else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < parks.size(); i++)
                            parks.get(i).setDistance(-1);
                        showLocationError();
                    }
                    Collections.sort(parks, new Comparator<Park>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Park park, Park other) {
                            return (int) (park.distance - other.distance);
                        }
                    });
                    listener.onLoadCompleted(parks);
                }
            });
        } else {
            getLocationPermission();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the code in showList() (mainly an ArrayAdapter):

```
void showList(final ArrayList<Park> parks) {

    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    finalParkList = parks;

    ArrayAdapter<Park> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Park>(this, 0, parks) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Park park = parks.get(position);

            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_park, null, false);

            TextView nameView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
            TextView typeView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.typeView);
            TextView distanceView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.distanceView);

            nameView.setText(park.name);
            typeView.setText(park.type);
            if (park.distance != -1)
                distanceView.setText(Distance.formatDistance(park.distance) + " entfernt");
            else
                distanceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    parkListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: what else do you have in ParkLoader? because what I see seems to be correct

Comment: @Rainmaker it's a lot of code so I decided not to put it in here but it contains code to load a file, convert it to Json, get some values and look for the current location and then send them back to the MainActivity using OnLoadCompleted which takes an ArrayList as parameter. Is it a problem that it uses the MainActivity context to do getAssets()?

Comment: I don't think so, asynctask uses activity in any case, as long as you do it in doInBackground this shouldn't block the ui. The most common problem is when people use .execute().get() but you don't in the code you provided. I cannot see fault in what you have here

Comment: Are you sure there is no other calling which can cause UI thread stuck . What `showList(parks)` method does ? Right now your code looks well.

Comment: @ADM I don't think so. My logs show that opening the json file takes the most time and after the AsyncTask executes the UI thread is working again. What else could possibly block it?

Comment: Add your code . of  `onPostExecute()` and `showList(parks)`.

Comment: @ADM I don't use `onPostExecute()`, `OnLoadCompleted` gets called directly from the findParks() functions. Maybe this could be a problem?

Comment: Add the code .I can not guess the issue .

Comment: @ADM I added the code for showList() and findNearbyParks(). The only thing left in ParkLoader is the function to load the json.

Comment: I think your Ui thread not stuck . Call `showList(parks)` inside `runOnUiThread()`. And then check .

Comment: @ADM but how can I use `runOnUIThread()?` The functions are outside of `doInBackground()`.

Comment: inside `onLoadCompleted()` .`runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
showList(parks);
})`

Comment: @ADM tried it, unfortunately it doesn't work either. Is it possible that this is a problem with the SwipeRefreshLayout? The call to `AsyncTask` is wrapped into a RefreshListener.

Comment: I can not say that code is incomplete. You are not using `StrictMode`? just make sure any UI update will be on UI thread and long running task will be on background thread .

Comment: @ADM StrictMode says there's disk reading done on the UI thread so I guess it still doesn't work properly.